# If UIImageview is still in the view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i want to write a if statement that checks and sees if a UIImageView is still in the view?
like

```
if (imageview isView){

}
```

Or is there another way of doing this? Like checking if a imageview is NULL or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [containsObject](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)

```
if(yourPArentView.subViews containsObject:yourImageVIew){


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the imageView's superview is your view.

```
if (imageView.superview == theView) {

}
```